# Extract value from variable

Tags: css, less

I just want to ask if it is possible in LESSCSS to use the extract function while the value is stored in LESS Variable?

This is what I'm using:

```
@basic: #ffffff, #000000, #333333;
@classes: white, black, gray;
.make-color(@i: length(@basic)) when (@i > 0) {
    .make-color(@i - 1);
    @color: extract(@basic, @i);
    @class: extract(@classes, @i);
    .@{class} {
            color: @color;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I want

```
  @white: #ffffff;
  @black: #000000;
  @gray: #333333;

  @basic: @white, @black, @gray;
  @classes: white, black, gray;
    .make-color(@i: length(@basic)) when (@i > 0) {
        .make-color(@i - 1);
        @color: extract(@basic, @i);
        @class: extract(@classes, @i);
        .@{class} {
                color: @color;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I tried the second one it returns a compiled css like this:

```
.white{
color: @white;
}
.black{
color: @black;
}
.gray{
color: @gray;
}
```

but my target is like this:

```
.white{
color: #ffffff;
}
.black{
color: #000000;
}
.gray{
color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: **P.S:** I want to store the value into a variable so use that I can use it into other elements.

Comment: At least LESS2CSS compiles to the desired result (version 2.0.0 and above). Here is a minimal example for the extract variable thing: `http://less2css.org/#{"less"%3A"%40var1%3A coconut%3B\n%40list%3A apple%2C pear%2C %40var1%2C orange%3B\n\n.class {\n value%3A extract(%40list%2C 3)%3B\n}"}`